# ng-sortable dragging not working, anymore

Tags: angularjs, ng-sortable

[image: Image of Yaktocat]

As you can see the dragging is not longer working, but it was before! 
It does the normal dragging of the image, but the others don't move to make space.

At first I thought it was the new chrome 43, but it is happening in Safari and Firefox.
I was in 1.1.7 of ng-sortable so I tried updating to 2.2.1 but didn't fix it. I went to 1.1.9 but nothing.

This is my bower deps in case you know of any compatibilities I don't.

```
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.5",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.5",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.5",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.2.13",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.0",
    "angular-google-maps": "~2.1.0",
    "ngstorage": "~0.3.0",
    "ngtoast": "~1.4.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "~1.6.5",
    "angular-ui-select": "~0.11.2",
    "highcharts-ng": "~0.0.7",
    "angular-bootstrap-colorpicker": "~3.0.8",
    "moment": "~2.8.4",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "angulartics": "~0.17.1",
    "angular-smart-table": "~1.4.11",
    "card": "~0.1.4",
    "angular-input-masks": "~1.3.1",
    "angular-seo": "*",
    "ng-sortable": "1.1.9",
    "dw-bxslider-4": "~4.2.3"
}
```

This is my jade template

```
ul.uploaded-file.uploaded-file-grid.feature-first(as-sortable="config.sortable", ng-model='property.photos')
  li.draggable.align-center(as-sortable-item, ng-repeat='image in property.photos')
    img.full-width(ng-src="{{image.small}}", as-sortable-item-handle)
    a.btn.btn-sm.btn-danger.icon-bin-2(ng-click="removeImage($index)", href="javascript:;", tooltip="Borrar")
```

And my config object, which I pass to as-sortable

```
{
  orderChanged: function (event) {
    $scope.update();
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve it?

Comment: Yes, look at this issue to know more https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable/issues/163